# How do I create a function in postgres that updates a field with a series of 'REGEXP_REPLACE's

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function that homogenises text columns. It's a series of regex_replaces in a case when function.

I believe that the following (shortened) code should give me the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_data(address_token text) RETURNS 
setof text
AS
$$
BEGIN
return case when address_token like '%allee' OR address_token LIKE '%ally' OR address_token LIKE '%aly' then regexp_replace(address_token,'(allee|ally|aly)$', 'alley')
when address_token like '%annex' OR address_token LIKE '%annx' OR address_token LIKE '%anx' then regexp_replace(address_token,'(annex$|annx$|anx$)', 'anex')
when address_token like '%arc' then regexp_replace(address_token ,'arc$', 'arcade')

.
.
.

when address_token like '%wls' then regexp_replace(address_token ,'wls$', 'wells') else address_token;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE newtable AS
select postcode, (clean_data(address1)) as address1 (clean_data(address2)) as address2, (clean_data(address3)) as address3
from oldtable where postcode SIMILAR TO '(a|b)%';
```

However when I run this, I get the error message:

```
RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set
LINE 5:   return case when address_token like '%allee' OR address_to...
             ^
HINT:  Use RETURN NEXT or RETURN QUERY.
```

When I take its advice and use 'RETURN QUERY' instead, I'm told:

```
syntax error at or near "case"
LINE 5:   return query case when address_token like '%allee' OR addr...
```

Which I'm not finding very helpful.

What is the correct way to write this function?

I'm relatively new to SQL functions and am not 100 % sure about:

- 'returns setof text': is this going to return a field as expected?
- language: is this SQL or plpgsql
- 'RETURN" vs 'RETURN NEXT' vs 'RETURN QUERY': I'm not sure of the difference here

I've been googling for the past couple of hours with very little progress and very little understanding gained so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key error is that setof returns multiple rows of data: your function operates on one row at a time, so should simply return `text`. You've tagged this as plpgsql, but as it's only a single statement it would work equally well as SQL: the `BEGIN` and `END` statements are not required in SQL, and you would `select` rather than `return` the result. While your `CASE` statement is quite long, this is still a simple function with one input and one output as [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-BASE-FUNCTIONS).

A second error is that you missed out the `END` of the `CASE` statement: you need to end the case, then end the plpgsql function, so you'll have a double end.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION clean_data(address_token text) RETURNS text
AS
$$
BEGIN
return case when address_token like '%allee' OR address_token LIKE '%ally' OR address_token LIKE '%aly' then regexp_replace(address_token,'(allee|ally|aly)$', 'alley')
.
.
.
when address_token like '%wls' then regexp_replace(address_token ,'wls$', 'wells') else address_token
end;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks. I was under the impression that returning text would return a single string as opposed to a column of strings.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL manual says:

> SQL function can be declared to return a set (that is, multiple rows)
>   by specifying the function's return type as SETOF sometype, or
>   equivalently by declaring it as RETURNS TABLE(columns)

So, you use setof to return `rows`. In your case you are returning a 'field'. So you should change your return to `RETURNS TEXT` (without setof) or if you need a table, you should set the output of your case into a record or row.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the case expression at all.  Just use your regexp_replace functions as is, they already embody the predicates in your case statements.

Better yet put your expressions into a table and just loop through them:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1712/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table samples(address_token text);
create table replacements(exp varchar(30), value varchar(30), flags varchar(10));

INSERT INTO samples
    (address_token)
VALUES
    ('DB Ally'),
    ('SQL Annex'),
    ('Penny Arc'),
    ('CPU Wls')
;

INSERT INTO replacements
    (exp, value, flags)
VALUES
    ('(allee|ally|aly)$', 'alley', 'i'),
    ('(annex$|annx$|anx$)', 'anex', 'i'),
    ('arc$', 'arcade', 'i'),
    ('wls$', 'wells', 'i')
;

create or replace function clean_data(address_token text) returns text
as
$$
DECLARE
  r record;
  result text;
BEGIN
  result := address_token;
  for r in (select exp, value, flags from replacements) loop
      result := regexp_replace(result, r.exp, r.value, r.flags);
  end loop;
  return result;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from replacements
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1712/1/0)**:

```
|                 exp |  value | flags |
|---------------------|--------|-------|
|   (allee|ally|aly)$ |  alley |     i |
| (annex$|annx$|anx$) |   anex |     i |
|                arc$ | arcade |     i |
|                wls$ |  wells |     i |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select address_token, clean_data(address_token) new_val
  from samples
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c1712/1/1)**:

```
| address_token |      new_val |
|---------------|--------------|
|       DB Ally |     DB alley |
|     SQL Annex |     SQL anex |
|     Penny Arc | Penny arcade |
|       CPU Wls |    CPU wells |
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer Sentinel. I've selected @Adrian Cox's answer as it corrected my query as requested. I had thought about using a method similar to the one described by you but I was under the impression that when the replacements table becomes very large, looping through it may become quite time expensive. However, Adrian mentions that case when also operates on one row at a time so it may end up taking a similar amount of time. I'll experiment when I next get a chance.

Comment: Also thanks for sharing SQLfiddle, Looks like a valuable resource that I wasn't aware existed.

Comment: Using the CASE statement has one benefit, in that once one branch is selected no further branches are tested, but for the selected branch, the same test is repeated by regular expression.  To get similar short circuiting feature in the for loop version, add an exit condition: `EXIT WHEN result <> address_token;` just before the `END LOOP;`